# how to invert transform a UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, transform, core-plot

I am using core-plot library to draw a bar-chart on my iPhone application and the problem arises when I try to add a label or some other views to the graph,

Actually the view I added is drawn vertically invert [like this ........](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?f36691f297.png)

The code is like

```
UILabel *lbl= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 90, 70, 25)];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [lbl setText:@"HELLO"];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];
```

I am not daring to play with core-plot library.

So is there any other way to do the things right? should I do a transform before adding the views?

If this is the solution then this will be costly because I have to add more than one subview.

Hoping my question is clear to everybody.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, it looks like the core-plot view is inverted using a CGAffineTransform. Your view is probably inheriting the inversion from its superview.
It's actually quite simple to do,

```
lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);
```

Should do the trick.
If you have to do it many times perhaps simplify it with something like,

```
CGAffineTransform verticalFlip = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);
lbl.transform = verticalFlip;
otherLbl.transform = verticalFlip;
```

etc...

An x-axis flip would be `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);`

Comment: Great I did it like.... lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(verticalFlip,0,-300);

Comment: Yes, we do this to match the coordinate systems for drawing between the Mac and iPhone.  If you want this to be simpler, my recommendation would be to not add your UILabel to the graph's CPLayerHostingView, but to create a superview that encompasses the graph and add the UILabel to that.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid guessing actual transform values you can try to use `CGAffineTransformInvert` function:

```
lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(self.view.transform);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to transform a layer which is 3D model you need to handle it as follows,

Swift 5:

```swift
// To inverse the graph vertically
annotationGraph.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1))
```

otherwise you would have receive this,

> Cannot assign value of type 'CGAffineTransform' to type 'CATransform3D'